# How to stop decreasing number if it have reach zero?

Tags: javascript

I have a button that when it clicked it will decrease the number by 50. So what i want is if the var reach zero, even if you click the button, it won't go negative. It just gonna stay at zero.(answer using javascript please, thanks :) )
(if you can, please also answer me how to prevent the `<div id="goldMine">` from overlapping the `<div class="resources>`. Thanks!

*My html(if you want):

```js
//Loading
console.log('Loading...')
console.log('Gathering information from server...')
console.log('Gathering information from server...succeed!')
console.log('Putting spells book in A-Z...complete!')
console.log('Making gold mines...')
console.log('Making gold mines...suceed!')
console.log('Smithering weapon...')
console.log('Smithering weapon...suceed!')
console.log('Sweeping the dusts...')
console.log('Sweeping the dusts...complete!!WAIT A SPIDER CRAWLING ON ME AHHHH')
console.log("Preventing cheaters who looking at the console...Wait, you're looking at it right now!")
console.log('Drawing maps...complete!')
console.log('Burning trees...complete!')
console.log('Typing stuff in the console...done!')
console.log('Adding easter egg...?')
console.log("Killing bugs...oops, there's a bug in the bug :/'")
console.log('FINISH LOADING. STARTING GAME!! Have fun playing!')
//Set the var
var coins = 0;
var golds = 0;
//Bought the woodden shortsword
function boughtWoodenSword() {
 document.getElementById()
}
//increase coins per 0.45 seconds
window.setInterval(
 function () {
  coins ++
  document.getElementById("numberOfCoins").innerHTML = "You got " + coins + " coins!";
  checkConditions()
 }, 450);
 
//Mine a gold every 10 second
window.setInterval(
 function () {
  golds ++
  document.getElementById("numberOfGolds").innerHTML = "You mined " + golds + " golds!";
 }, 10000);

//Get a coin when clicked button
function addCoins() {
 coins ++;
 document.getElementById('numberOfCoins').innerHTML = "You got " + coins + " coins!";
 checkConditions()
};

//When enough coins, add 10 coins button will appear and when clicked add 10 coins
function add10Coins() {
 coins += 10;
 document.getElementById('numberOfCoins').innerHTML = "You got " + coins + " coins!";
 checkConditions()
};

//Throw some coins for the poor(Wow, you're generous!)
function throwCoins() {
 coins -= 10;
 document.getElementById('numberOfCoins').innerHTML = "You got " + coins + " coins!";
 checkConditions()
};

//Check for conditions

//check add 10
function checkConditions() {
 if (coins >= 50) {
  document.getElementById('add10Coins').style.display = "inline-block";
 }
 //check open shop
 if (coins >= 500) {
  document.getElementById('shop').style.display = "inline-block";
 };
};
```

```css
#shop {
 font-style: normal;
}
#goldMine {
 border: 2px solid black;
}
pre {
 font-style: normal;
}
var {
 font-style: normal;
}
button {
 font-size:15px;
 margin :3px;
}
```

```html
<HTML style=font-family:sans-serif>
<head>
<title>Idle RPG</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico"/>
<script src=Scripts/gameScript.js> </script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href=Scripts/pageStyle.css>
<body>
<p id="numberOfCoins">You got 0 coin</p>
<p id="numberOfGolds">You mined 0 gold</p>
<button onclick="addCoins()">Collect a coin.</button>
<button onclick="throwCoins()">Throw 10 coins away.</button>
<button style=display:none id="add10Coins" onclick="add10Coins()">Get 10 coins.</button>
<br>
<div style=float:right class="resources">
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <legend id="resource"><h3>RESOURCES</h3></legend>  
    Iron: <var id='numberOfIrons'>0<var><br>
    Silver:  <var id='numberOfSilver'>0<var><br>
    Coal:  <var id='numberOfCoal'>0<var><br>
  </fieldset>
</form>
</div>
<div id="goldMine">
    <pre style= border: 3px solid black>
_GOLD MINE_       _IRON MINE_       _GOLD MINE_       _IRON MINE_
|         |       |         |       |         |       |         |
|         |       |         |       |         |       |         |
    </pre>
</div>
<div style=display:none id="shop">
 <pre>
<h2>SHOP</h2>
"Hi, im a blacksmith. I see you have a lot of coins, so i think that you might be interest in my weapons!"
Buy a item to unlock a new item!

Woodden Sword      
   .
  / \
  | |
  | |
  |.|
  |.|
  |:|
  |:|
'--8--'
   8
   O
Cost: 2000 coins    
<button onclick='coins -= 2000;'>Buy</button>

Iron Sword
   .
  / \
  | |
  | |
  |.|
  |.|
  |:|
  |:|
 _|*|_
\--+--/
   8
   8
   O
Cost: 50 Golds
<button onclick='golds -= 50'>Buy</button>
 </pre>
</div>
</HTML>
```

Comment: `if (coins < 0) coins = 0`

Comment: `coins = Math.max(0, coins - 50);`

Comment: Where should I put this im my code?

Comment: @PaulS. Isn't a conditional operator faster than calling a function ?

Comment: @FlyingGambit not always. In this case, `Math.max` is a tiny bit (2%) faster https://jsperf.com/math-max-vs-conditional

Comment: @PaulS. Tried it on Chrome 55.0 and it shows ternary lt as fastest and Math.max as 5% slower. Which browser are you using ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### In JavaScript:

```
// In the onClick event handler:
coins = (coins <= 50) ? 0 : coins - 50;
return coins;
```

### In words:

If coins are less than or equal to fifty make coins zero; otherwise, reduce coins by fifty.

## I see you're using inline JavaScript:

```
<button onclick='(golds <= 50) ? golds = 0 : gold -= 50;'>Buy</button>
```

While it's possible to do that, it's best to keep logic like this out of the HTML. It's a better idea to set an eventListener on that element that responds to click events.

```
// used to be:
// <button onclick='golds -= 50'>Buy</button>
<button id="sellIronSword">Buy</button>

// Inside a <script>
var ironSwordButton = document.getElementById('sellIronSword');
ironSwordButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    coins = (coins <= 50) ? 0 : coins - 50;
    return coins;
}
```

## Try it out:

```js
var coins = 150;
var ironSwordButton = document.getElementById('sellIronSword');

ironSwordButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    coins = (coins <= 50) ? 0 : coins - 50;
    
    document.getElementById('coins').innerHTML = coins;
});
```

```html
<h3>Coins: <span id="coins">150</span></h3>
<hr />
<label>
  <span>Buy Iron Sword</span>
  <button id="sellIronSword">Buy</button>
</label>
```